# AngularJS init firing twice

Tags: angularjs, initialization

I have the following code for AngularJS.  Within is a checkStatus function that invokes a web api to check a status of a user's PC. The problem I'm having is that the checkStatus() function is firing twice and hitting the back-end service twice.   I do not understand why.

```
<script>

    (function() {
        var pageApp = angular.module('pageApp', ['commandAPI']);

        function PageCtrl ($scope, $http, commandAPI) {
            $scope.checkStatus();
        }

        angular
            .module('pageApp')
            .controller('pageAppCtrl', PageCtrl);

    })();

</script>
```

Comment: Could you provide more info of checkStatus() function? What method are you using for reach the server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems that somehow the properties of the app and the controller were applied to two HTML elements within the page.  Not sure how that happened but there it was.